# Why the author's solution of this problem doesn't consider $U=V$ case.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $T: V \rightarrow  W$ is a
> surjective linear map of $V$ onto $W$. Prove that there is a subspace
> $U$ of $V$ such that $T|_{U}$ is an isomorphism of $U$ onto $W$. (Here
> $T|_{U}$ means the function $T$ restricted to $U$. In other
> words, $T|_{U}$ is the function whose domain is $U$, with $T|_{U}$
> defined by $T|_{U}(u)=Tu$ for every $u \in U$.)

As mentioned in the title, I just let $U=V$ for this problem. Which seems reasonable to me. However, the author of the book gave another solution, which seems unnecessarily complex to me. There is no additional sentence for this problem s.t $U \neq V$.

So, is $U=V$ a valid answer too?

Comment: Consider $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $W = \mathbb{R}$ and $T(x,y) = x$. In that case $U$ can't be $V$ to have an isomorphism.

Comment: The fact that $T: V \rightarrow W$ is a surjective linear map implies that $\dim V \geq \dim W$. It may well be the case that $\dim V > \dim W$, and in that specific case letting $U = V$ would not work.